# jQuery Validation adding a new method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

what I'm wanting to do is add a new validation method that will validate if 2 fields are not equal DEPENDING if a radio button is ticked (see here - http://jsfiddle.net/dazziep/uVnQ4/9/)

The code I have works, but I have had to fudge it a little by adding the field in the actual method where I would rather pass it through.

So at the moment I have ...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("test", function(value, element, param){
   // check if dependency is met
   if (!this.depend(param, element)) return "dependency-mismatch";
   return value != $("#ImEqDepEq").val();
   },
   jQuery.format("Should not match Equality value.")
);`
```

I obviously just want ($("#ImEqDepEq").val()) to be another parameter that I pass in.

I hope this makes some kind of sense, I'm rubbish at explaining things :(

cheers

Daz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass additional info to the rule using `param` option.

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        ImEqDep: {
            test: {
                depends: function () {
                    return $("#ImEqDepRad1Yes").is(':checked');
                },
                param: '#ImEqDepEq'
            }
        }
    }
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("test", function (value, element, param) {
    // check if dependency is met
    if (!this.depend(param, element)) return "dependency-mismatch";
    return value != $(param).val();
}, jQuery.format("Should not match Equality value."));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uVnQ4/11/)

Comment: spot on, works a treat.. I can't believe how simple and obvious the solution was.. I actually feel a bit silly asking now :)